# методом get из из листа integer получить число для сравнения

Tags: java, динамические-массивы

Вот лист   `TimeRecord  = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
 Если печатать значение элемента 0, то он печатается

```
System.out.println(TimeRecord.get(0));
```

А если я хочу сравнить if(TimeRecord.get(0) > 10 ) то пишет что нельзя сравнить объект с числом. Но ведь это уже не объект , а его значение? Как мне сравнить значение элемента листа?

**UPD** Кажись так `TimeRecord.get(0).equals(10)`

Но всё же скажите почему TimeRecord.get(0) объект , а не значение элемента , которое является integer

Comment: Как создаётся список? Приведенная вами строка `TimeRecord  = new ArrayList<Integer>();` некорректна и нескомпилируется. Вангую, что Переменная, ссылающаяся на `new ArrayList<Integer>();` не знает о типе данных, хранящемся в этом списке.

Comment: Не в этом суть. я не полный код описал , TimeRecord уже объявлен как ArrayList.  equals возвращает 1 , - 1 и 0 . Но почему то это получается использовать в конструкции if(TimeRecord.get(0).equals(10)) {}  . Ну можно решить что -1 воспринимается как false , 1 = true, но 0..короче я не знаю как эта конструкция работает

Comment: ЭХ блин , точно. Лист был объявлен как ArrayList , а не как ArrayList<Integer>()